# Why does this code return None when I don't put the else statement, but it doesn't return None when I put the else statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygal

Why does this return the country codes?

```
from pygal.maps.world import COUNTRIES 

def get_country_code(country_name): 
    """Return the Pygal 2-digit country code for the given country."""
    for code, name in COUNTRIES.items(): 
        if name == country_name:
            return code 
    return None 

print(get_country_code('Andorra'))
print(get_country_code('United Arab Emirates')
```

Why doesn't this return the country codes?

```
from pygal.maps.world import COUNTRIES 

def get_country_code(country_name): 
    """Return the Pygal 2-digit country code for the given country."""
    for code, name in COUNTRIES.items(): 
        if name == country_name:
            return code 
        return None 

print(get_country_code('Andorra'))
print(get_country_code('United Arab Emirates')
```

The main difference is how I indented the 'return None.' Even if I put the else statement it doesn't return the codes. Can someone please explain this to me? I'm new in programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentation **is** the difference -- check your indentation closely. in the second example, the `return none` is INSIDE the `for code` loop.  So it returns None as soon as `if name == country_name' fails once.

Python indentation acts like braces in C-based languages or Begin-End in BASIC dialects.  It's the main idiosyncrasy of Python.

Comment: True. But if I use the else statement and put it inside the for code, it still returns None. Can you explain it to me why?

Comment: Just edited the answer with more detail, but you really must get the indentation thing down -- with experiments like these -- to understand it fully.

Answer (score 0):

Ok JLH is correct.  In the second set of code: Since the else is in the for loop the first name in the list will trigger the else code (unless you are looking for the first 1 on the list) which will return none.  So unless the first element is the one you are looking for it will always return None.